# Sort Pojo class

Tags: java, android

this is my POJO class which has the following elements:

```
public class ModelGettyImages {   private ArrayList<String> title;}
```

Now I want to sort this alphabetically with my

```
 ArrayList<ModelGettyImages> ImagesList;
```

This is what i have done so far using Comparator but the POJO consists of ArrayList so i can't figure out how to sort it.

```
  if( ascending )
        {
            Log.d("Ass","True");

            Collections.sort(ImagesList, new Comparator<ModelGettyImages>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(ModelGettyImages lhs, ModelGettyImages rhs) {
                    return lhs.
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: "the POJO consists of ArrayList so i can't figure out how to sort it." - you can be sure that we are unable to figure out your business requirements for you.

Comment: @chintan compareTo to cannot be applied to Arraylist

Answer (score 0):

> YOU CAN'T COMPARE ARRAYLIST

Pass imageList as simple object of Model class then after follow my way.

You have to compare with String accordingly.

`return lhs.getImageName().compareTo(rhs.getImageName());`

> FYI - replace `getImageName()` with your pojo class String method.

This will work for sure.

Comment: i don't want to change to just String in my POJO

Comment: Forget then you can't compare arraylist. :)